# Activity diagram with alternative paths

Tags: uml, workflow-activity

Should the alternative paths of an use case be included in the activity diagram??

Comment: Is the use-case easier to understand if they're in the same diagram or separate diagrams?

Comment: The use case definiton include an alternative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to model use case realization for the whole use case, definitely yes. However, if the alternative paths are extending use cases, you probably want to use [Interaction overview diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_interactionoverviewdiagram.html) so you can reference existing interaction and do not have to duplicate it. Also as a comment to your question suggest, it might be reasonable to split a diagram when it will be too big.